# How do I make the code to find the major and minor values in a random?

Tags: java

I've do for the case finding the major value:

```
double x = 2, y, z = 0, minor = 0, major = 0, equal = 0, g = 0;
int n;
String text1;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    n = (int) (11 * Math.random());
    if (n > major) {
        major = n;
    }
    text1 = i + ". Random= \n" + n;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text1);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The major number was: " + major);
```

But, I don't know how to do that for the minor value, because I can't start putting in a "if" the condition "n < minor".

Comment: Why can't you...?

Comment: you have to set minor to Integer.MAX_VALUE and major to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @Tunaki For me it's not logical to say n<minor with minor=0, because the random only take positive numbers.

Comment: Yes, then don't have `minor = 0`, because, you're right, no positive value can ever be lower than 0.

Comment: And maybe it is just me, but I find your wording confusing. You want to determine min/max values in a random sequence... Not majors./minors.

Comment: @Tunaki It shouldn't be lower than 1. 0 isn't a positive integer.

Comment: @Drew Sigh. The statement "no positive value can ever be lower than 0" is true even without being highly pedantic about it. I could even say "no positive value can ever be lower than -10" and still be right... None of this nitpick will help OP here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    n = (int) (11 * Math.random());
    if (n > major) {
        major = n;
    }
    if (i==1) minor=n;
    else if (minor>n) minor=n;
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize `minor` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is the maximum value of an `int`, then you could use `n < minor` to find the minimum.

Otherwise you could always initialize `minor` with the first random value, and perform the comparison only with the subsequent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like :

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

int n;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    n = (int) (11 * Math.random());
    integers.add(n);
}

Integer min = Collections.min(integers);
Integer max = Collections.max(integers);
```

Comment: Is my fault, i don't especificate that i'm new using Java, then i'm only know the basic codes like "if" "else" "for". But, thanks for give me a solution.